# Using Noto Sans Symbols

Tags: fonts

I have been using some symbols (card suits etc) from Deja Vu on a Windows system using Lualatex.  But I don't see them when I switch the font to Noto Sans Symbols.  The font appears to be correctly installed - I can see it in the Control Panel and it's working in MS Word e.g. "The quick ♣ ..."

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}%

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage{newunicodechar}


\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
%\newfontfamily{\symbolfont}{Noto Sans Symbols} 
\newfontfamily{\symbolfont}{Deja Vu Sans} 

\DeclareRobustCommand\Ts{{\symbolfont ♣}}
\newunicodechar{♣}{{\symbolfont♣}}


\begin{document}

Two clubs 2\Ts{}

Two clubs 2♣

\end{document}
```

The log file includes the following:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSansSymbols(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Sans Symbols' with options [Scale=MatchUppercase].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[0.9565830048011242]"NotoSansSymbols:mode=node;scrip
t=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[0.9565830048011242]"NotoSansSymbols/B:mode=node;scr
ipt=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[0.9565830048011242]"NotoSansSymbols/I:mode=node;scr
ipt=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[0.9565830048011242]"NotoSansSymbols/BI:mode=node;sc
ript=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 


Missing character: There is no ? (U+2663) in font NotoSansSymbols:mode=node;sc
ript=latn;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ? (U+2663) in font NotoSansSymbols:mode=node;sc
ript=latn;language=DFLT;!
```

Comment: Did you check that it's actually Noto that has this char? Word sometimes uses fallbacks…

Comment: Yes, they are in e.g. https://fontinfo.opensuse.org/fonts/NotoSansSymbolsRegular.html as char 2663 etc.

Comment: that place is empty in NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf. The above list shows only what should be ...

Comment: @Herbert That certainly explains the problem!  Where can one find a list of what  is actually implemented in the various Noto fonts?

Comment: @TeXnician I think you're right - Word seems to have silently pulled it from Lucida.

Answer (score 4):

Noto Sans Symbols2 seems to have your char:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\symbolfont}{Noto Sans Symbols2} 
\begin{document}
\symbolfont \Uchar"2663
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, now I'll check for the others I need.  Suits are all there \DeclareRobustCommand\Ks{\color{red}{\symbolfont\char"2666}}

Answer (score 3):

```
otfinfo -g DejaVuSans.ttf | grep club
```

has an output, but

```
otfinfo -g NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf | grep club
```

not. With `otfinfo -g <font>` you'll get a list of the symbolic names. `otfinfo` needs the fontname with full path if you are not in the fonts directory.

Comment: That works fine C:\Windows\Fonts>otfinfo -g notosanssymbols2-regular.ttf | grep club
club_gobliquestroke-phaistosDisc
club

Answer (score 0):

There's a very  useful  [search tool](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) at https://www.fileformat.info

Say, for example, you want to find what fonts support "less than or equal to" you input some or all of that text and find that the symbol is Unicode U+2264.  Clicking on the link leads to fonts that [support U+2264](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/fontsupport.htm)

In this case, Noto isn't listed which can't really be correct - such a common symbol must be supported.  But you can click on to an Adobe Flash link to fonts installed on your [local machine](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%89%A4%20-%20LESS-THAN%20OR%20EQUAL%20TO%20%28U%2B2264%29) and it's in Noto Sans, Noto Serif, Noto Mono, Noto Symbol2 (and many other fonts if you prefer not to use Noto!)